Is there a way to avoid the 'static lifetime requirement in this implementation?
I'm trying to better understand concurrency in Rust. I got the followin assignment:

A Looper is a paradigm frequently used in reactive. When created, a Looper creates a queue of generic Message objects and a thread.
The thread waits - without consuming CPU cycles - for messages to be present in the queue
extracts one by one in the order of arrival, and processes them. The Looper constructor receives two parameters, both of type (pointer to) function: process(…) and cleanup(). The first is a function responsible for processing individual messages received through the queue; this function accepts a single input parameter of type Message and returns nothing; The second and private function of arguments and return value and will be invoked by the thread encapsulated in the Looper when it will stand for terminal.
Looper offers a unique public, thread-safe method, in addition to the service ones, needed to manage its second life cycle: send(msg), which accepts a generic object of type as a parameter Message that will be inserted into the queue and subsequently extracted from the thread and forwarded to processing function. When a Looper object is destroyed, it must be ensured that thread contained within it calls the second function passed in the constructor and then terminates.
Implement it, using the Rust language. As a guide, keeping in mind its methods they must be thread-safe.

I want to understand if the 'static lifetime for T is necessary or it can be avoided acting differently;
and I'm not sure that at run time it would work as it should (especially when dropping the Looper).
use crossbeam_channel::{bounded, Receiver, Sender};
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

struct Message<T> {
    msg: T,
}

struct Queue<T> {
    message_queue: Mutex<VecDeque<Message<T>>>,
    cv: Condvar,
}

struct Looper<T> {
    queue: Arc<Queue<T>>,
    handle: JoinHandle<()>,
    terminate: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl<T> Drop for Looper<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.terminate.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
        self.queue.cv.notify_all();
    }
}

// Implement methods for Looper
impl<T: Send + 'static> Looper<T> {
    fn new(process: fn(Message<T>), cleanup: fn()) -> Looper<T> {
        let queue = Arc::new(Queue {
            message_queue: Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()),
            cv: Condvar::new(),
        });
        let queue_clone = Arc::clone(&queue);
        let end_thread = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
        let end_thread_clone = Arc::clone(&end_thread);
        Looper {
            queue,
            handle: thread::spawn(move || {
                loop {
                    let mut lock = queue_clone.message_queue.lock().unwrap();

                    while lock.is_empty() && !end_thread_clone.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                        lock = queue_clone.cv.wait(lock).unwrap();
                    }

                    if end_thread_clone.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if let Some(message) = lock.pop_back() {
                        drop(lock);
                        process(message);
                    }
                }
                cleanup();
            }),
            terminate: end_thread,
        }
    }
    fn send(&self, msg: Message<T>) {
        let mut queue = self.queue.message_queue.lock().unwrap();
        queue.push_back(msg);
        self.queue.cv.notify_all();
    }
}


Why don't you use a channel?

To answer your question, stop and think: semantically (without thinking about actual code), is 'static required here? If yes, then it is required in code too. If not, it may still be required in code, but may not be.

This could work. Note that the looper has to run inside this function. By using the Sender struct I introduced, it is even possible to send from outside the scope.

The 'static lifetime is necessary because of the thread you're using. A 'static bound on a type means that the type is allowed to live forever; this tends to apply to owned data types like String, but not borrowed types like &str (which, by definition, usually have some shorter lifetime requirement, because they must not outlive the data that they reference).
Because you're sending these messages to another thread (created with thread::spawn), and that thread has no limits on how much it can run, data that you send to it must necessarily be 'static, because that thread could theoretically outlive any other lifetime you could care to name.
Note that this requirement arises because you're using thread::spawn, which creates threads of unlimited lifetime. An alternative would be to use thread::scope, which allows for creating threads that are guaranteed not to outlive some lifetime. You would need to pass the Scope object into the Looper constructor for this to work.
